# PI Camera not lighting up when connected to CSI Camera connector but does light up when connected to DSI Display connector

Tags: camera, connection

I've purchased a PI Camera Module for my Raspberry PI 4+.

I connected it to CSI Camera Connector, applied all necessary updates to the Pi but could not get the camera to be detected when using Raspistill or vcgencmd get_camera. Also the camera light does not come on. Tried connecting the cable the other way round, still nothing.

I connected to the camera module to the DSI Display Connector and the camera light does come on. Raspistill or vcgencmd still do not detect camera (as its in wrong connection).

Does this mean my Pi itself has a broken CSI Camera Connector?

Thanks

Comment: You may have killed the camera by connecting it to the display connector. Did you enable the camera in configuration?

Comment: Yes I enabled it via the Interfaces option in raspi-config. However the light never came up when connecting via the CSI Camera Connector. I only connected to DSI as a last resort and was surprised to seem the camera light come on.

Comment: I believe the light only comes on when the camera is in use. Was the power off when you plugged it in? Post a photo of the camera plugged into the correct socket.

Comment: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera/3